# Is it possible to integrate GSN OpenGSN v2 meta-transactions into Gnosis Safe smart contracts?

Tags: transactions, gnosis-safe, meta-transactions, safe-core

Is it possible to integrate OpenGSN v2 into Gnosis Safe smart contracts?

I want to create functionality to create safes and pay fees for user transactions with GSN relayer. The internal approach of GNosis Safe doesn't satisfy this need because in this case all meta-transaction are paid by the corresponding safe's balance that owners interact with.

In GSN v2, (or ERC2771) the msg.sender is encoded in the transaction.data.

So if I inherit from this interface and change all msg.sender to _msgSender() is there a possibility to break other functionality of Safe??? is transaction.data utilized by any other functionality in this protocol already?

Or any other possible reasons it may not work out. I appreciate any tips or opinions!

Answer (score 2):

I am not pretty sure how to integrate open gsn2 into a Gnosis Safe contract, yet Safe has released the [relay-kit](https://docs.safe.global/learn/safe-core/safe-core-account-abstraction-sdk/relay-kit#gelato-syncfee) that uses [Gelato Relay](https://docs.gelato.network/developer-services/relay) under the hood to sponsor the transaction going through the safe.

Hope it helps!